# Order string in numerical order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Lets say, I have a table, and I want to order by field with some string and size. When I use `ORDER BY size`, it gets something like this:

```
size 100
size 105
size 110
size 115
size 85
size 90
size 95
```

String can be different in each row, this is just example, when there is same string - `size`. I want to return this:

```
size 85
size 90
size 95
size 100
size 105
size 110
size 115
```

I know, that ordering by numeric string can be done with `ORDER BY CAST(size AS UNSIGNED)`, but how to do this, when its not numeric string, but the field is string with number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simple way to do this is to use the length as a key:

```
order by length(size), size
```

Alternatively, use `substring_index()`:

```
order by substring_index(size, ' ', 1),
         substring_index(size, ' ', -1) + 0
```

The `+ 0` does silent conversion to convert the second value to a number.

Comment: `order by length(size), size` did the trick :-) thanks a lot. I should know this, its logical :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are partially right. You could just fetch the number from your alpha numeric column

```
SELECT   *
FROM     MyTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(size, LOCATE(' ',size)+1) AS SIGNED)
```

Comment: thank you, but string can be different, f.e. `red pattern 45`, `red pattern 50`, `red pattern 55`, etc...

Comment: Do you mean you will have size 45, red pattern 45 etc?

Comment: string is the same for each product, `order by length(size), size` did the trick; there can be more spaces in the string, but +1 for trying to help